# Difference between a SmartCard with and without an applet installed on it?

Tags: applet, development-environment, smartcard, globalplatform

Gemalto IDprime MD 830 SmartCard (amount 35$) has an applet installed on it. I want to know the difference between a java card that contains an applet and a blank SmartCard (amount 1-5$)? Is it secure/ good practice to write my own applet and install it in blank SmartCard?

Comment: Your card volume has to be big AND your expertise considerable for the self-made approach to become financially interesting. If your card requires a certification I see no chance. Using a native smart card may be a viable alternative if your application requirements are near mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemalto smartcard has an OS, when you buy a blank card it comes with nothing, you'll need an OS an then you could start installing you applet. Also you'll need so much time to develope a complete OS so, the best option to develop an applet is buy one smartcard with some stuff inside